# Keep scroll position during refresh

Tags: javascript, scroll

I have a web server that displays a list of rooms and displays there states. Every 30 seconds it refreshes to collect new events and display any state changes of the rooms.

The problem is that the refresh rate has to be fast so events are registered in real time but the user is moved back to the top of the list every time the page refreshes which is a problem when there can be several hundred rooms.

the server is made of .jsp files which I think are javascript as it says javascriptin the HTML tags near the top of the page.

I have only ever used javascript an add in for PHP so am a little unsure about it.

Does anyone know of a way I can store the scroll position of the user and reset it there when the page refreshes.

Thanks

Comment: *their. If you were using php+ajax you could load the data without refreshing the page at all. Can you post any code/more details?

Comment: JSP stand for JavaServer Pages, it is not Javascript.  That may help you in your search.

Comment: @Calum Im not using php. I am enhancing someone else's code (previous employee) and am not sure what I am doing as I only know php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store the value of scrollTop in a cookie, and then onload, set the scrollTop back to that value, but it will probably make for a jerky experience to the user.

You might want to try making XHR/Ajax calls for the new data and then appending it to the correct place on the page.

Your favorite JS library will make that pretty easy to do.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays you should use [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) instead of a cookie. A cookie will be shared across tabs (potentially being very confusing), while sessionStorage is unique to a tab:

> sessionStorage is similar to Window.localStorage, the only difference is while data stored in localStorage has no expiration set, data stored in sessionStorage gets cleared when the page session ends. A page session lasts for as long as the browser is open and survives over page reloads and restores. **Opening a page in a new tab or window will cause a new session to be initiated,** which differs from how session cookies work.